# Why do i get undefined when creating an multidimesional array in jquery (javascript)?

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I want to create a multidimensional array and loop through it. I know it's possible because I've read about it, but I still can't figure why this does not work...

```
var bundeslan = [
    ["city1"][19161],
    ["city2"][19162],
    ["city3"][19162]
];

console.log(bundeslan);
```

I want to associate each city with a number and use that number to identify a div.

My thought was to loop through the array like this...

```
//Start main loop
 $.each(bundeslan, function( key, value ) {

     //Inner loop
     $.each(key, function(innerKey, innerValue){
         alert(innerValue);
     });

 });
```

But why do I gut like `[undefined][undefined][undefined]` etc... in `console.log(bundeslan)`?

Comment: "I want to associate each city with a number" Sounds like you should be using an object instead of an array: `{"city1": 19161, "city2": 19162, "city3": 19162}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your array definition is not quite correct, try this:

```
var bundeslan = [
    ["city1", 19161],
    ["city2", 19162],
    ["city3", 19162]
];    
console.log(bundeslan);
```

I would also advise against the use of 2 dimensional arrays. If you want an associative array, use an object:

```
var bundeslan = {
    city1: 19161,
    city2: 19162,
    city3: 19162
};    
console.log(bundeslan);
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to make more sense in my case.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error. Do this.

```
var bundeslan = [
    [["city1"],[19161]],
    [["city2"],[19162]],
    [["city3"],[19162]]
];
```

And this will give you the desired result

```
$.each(bundeslan, function( key, value ) {
     //Inner loop
     console.log(value[1][0]);

 });
```

Comment: Note that this gives you a nested array three levels deep, each containing a single value. I don't think this is exactly what the OP is after.

Comment: Yeah, @RoryMcCrossan's method makes more sense though. However, if you insist on a multi dimensional array then this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimentional array should be somewhat look like this

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
```

Where as your code block looks wrong.

```
var bundeslan = [
[["city1"],[19161]],
[["city2"],[19162]],
[["city3"],[19162]]
```

];

```
console.log(bundeslan);
```

Comment: When doing like this I didn't get a multidimensional array. Just an array with a comma after the the city.